# Codeigniter4 - return array data as JSON not as XML by default

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am just trying to play with the new Codeiginiter4 framework. I have created one route & attached it to one simple method `todos` which is supposed to return a list of todos(task) as JSON when I try to hit the URL but it returns it as XML format.
The code is simple,

```
class Home extends BaseController
{
    use ResponseTrait;

    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function todos()
    {   
        return $this->respondCreated(['todos' => ['task' => 'Check out new CI4']]);
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

// Result

```
<response>
<todos>
<task>Check out new CI4</task>
</todos>
</response>
```

Later I discovered that if I explicitly encode the array as JSON(using json_encode) it returns the result as JSON in the browser. Like this,

```
public function todos()
{   
    return $this->respondCreated(json_encode(['todos' => ['task' => 'Check out new CI4']]));
}
```

**So my question is there a way to by default return array as JSON format in the browser in CI4?**

CI Version I am using: v4.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for an xml response so CI4 is giving you what you asked. You should define your http header to ask for json before you return your response.

```
public function todos()
    {   
       $this->request->setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $this->respondCreated(['todos' => ['task' => 'Check out new CI4']]);
    }
```

Note : if you always want json response you can go to `app/Config/Format.php` and comment out one line so your `$supportedResponseFormats` variable looks like this :

```
    public $supportedResponseFormats = [
        'application/json',
//      'application/xml', // machine-readable XML
        'text/xml', // human-readable XML
    ];
```

Problem is you're removing CI4 the ability to handle xml response this way.

Check out CI4 great documentation for more details : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/api_responses.html#handling-response-types

Comment: Your solution works. I hade read the docs but it is not that much clearly mentioned I guess.